# How to run a Wayland program from SSH?

Tags: window-manager, wayland

I only have SSH access to a computer that is connected to an HDMI display. The display shows a basic TTY asking for a login.

How can I run a Wayland GUI program so it shows on the HDMI display?

```
[liam@brick:~] loginctl
SESSION  UID USER    SEAT  TTY
      1  997 greeter seat0 tty1
      9 1000 liam          pts/0

2 sessions listed.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "basic tty" turned out to be the 'agreety' frontend for greetd. From SSH, I was able to run `agretty` with the `GREETD_SOCK` environment variable set to greetd's unix socket in `/run/`. After a successful login, agretty asks for a command which shows on the HDMI display.

Hope this helps!